# VideoView искажаются пропорции. Как настроить

Tags: android, videoview

Имеется VideoView, в котором проигрывается видео. Видео не помещается по высоте, высота становится меньше и видео получается слишком толстым. Как сделать, чтобы толщина подстраивалась под высоту?

Answer (score 0):

Допустим у вас разметка:

```
...
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/video_player_progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</FrameLayout>
...
```

Тогда в активити это реализуется так:

```
public class VideoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FrameLayout videoContainer;
    VideoView videoView;
    MediaController mediaController;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(mp -> {
            mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener((mp1, width, height) -> {
                adjustAspectRatio(width, height);
                // Re-Set the videoView that acts as the anchor for the MediaController
                mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
            });

        });
    }

    private void adjustAspectRatio(int videoWidth, int videoHeight) {
        int viewHeight = videoContainer.getHeight();
        double videoAspectRatio = (double) videoWidth / videoHeight;

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = videoContainer.getLayoutParams();
        // limited by narrow width; restrict height
        lp.width = (int) (viewHeight * videoAspectRatio);
        videoContainer.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

VideoView должно обязательно лежать внутри FrameLayout, тогда пропорции сохраняются.